# Display polygon using Google API in angularjs application

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-maps

I want to do the same as this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Cbk9J/188/) : display the map and let the user draw a polygon, edit it and/or clear it. The problem is that I’m using angular but even if, I want to use the same code as  the example. The problem I’m facing now is that the map is not displayed.

Those are my includes in the `index.html`:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=drawing">
</script>


<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
```

and this is the map part in `myView.html`:

```
                <section id="placeholder">
                    <div id="map" ></div>
                </section>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null
    at Object._.vg (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=drawing:87:391)
at new Ag (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=drawing:89:76)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> 
    at j (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:29999)
    at k (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:30313)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null

usually occurs since map container (`<div id="map" ></div>`) is not yet ready once the map is initialized or could not be found.

For the first scenario you could utilize `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load',initMap)` to ensure the map is getting initialized once the DOM is ready.

Example

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MapCtrl', ['$scope',
        function ($scope) {
            $scope.initMap = function () {
                var center = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.870501, 151.206704);
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 12,
                    center: center,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
                };
                $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
            
            };
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load',$scope.initMap);
        }]);
```

```css
#map {
    height: 240px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MapCtrl">
        <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if I'm using jQuery code inside the angular controller, will it works?

Comment: @Llg, surely it will

Answer (score 0):

You have omitted your angular code. It's hard to say for sure what's wrong without looking at the where exactly the map div resides and at what point of time is google map initialised.

My most intelligent guess is, as from the error message, it is most probably an issue of trying to initialise the map before the div has loaded.

It is likely (very) that the code where you initialize your map is executed after the above  element is in DOM.

Since you are using AngularJS, the map will likely be initialised inside a controller. I cant be sure without seeing the app structure, etc.

Also, make sure you give a height and width to your map.